# How to get different versions of file in OneDrive using MS Graph API?

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am referring to the MSDN documentation for the Graph API, I am using python and graph explorer to get hold of different attributes for a file/item in OneDrive. But I am unable to find any information around managing and querying multiple versions for a file.

Comment: Microsoft Graph doesn't have the ability to access file versions right now, although it's very close to being released. You would need to use the SharePoint REST API to access file versions currently.

Comment: @RyanGregg thanks! is it something that we will have on our horizon soon like in a couple of months or is it scheduled for release next year?

Comment: Can't promise anything but it's more on the couple of months side.

Comment: Looking forward already :-)